# Sitecore CM login not redirecting to identity server

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-commerce, identity-server

I have installed `Sitecore 10.2 XM` in my `local machine`. It's installed 3 sites (CM, CD and IdentityServer).

When I access the `IdentityServer` URL https://test.identityserver.localhost/ it works fine. I am able to login and logout without any issues.

When I access the `CM` URL https://test.cm.localhost/sitecore/login I am expecting this should redirect me to `IdentityServer` site and after successful login redirect me to `CM` site. But this is not happening and when I access the `CM` URL https://test.cm.localhost/sitecore/login it is going to https://test.cm.localhost/sitecore/login?fbc=1 I am able to login successful though. But I expect it should go to `IdentityServer` site when I login/logout.

In the file, `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IDS\test.cm.localhost\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config`, I have the following setting:

```
<sc.variable name="identityServerAuthority" value="https://test.identityserver.localhost" />
```

Below is my `IdentityServer` config file `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IDS\test.identityserver.localhost\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
<Sitecore>
<IdentityServer>
  <CertificateThumbprint>8C0635270629989F235AD625692FC9220F0C1400</CertificateThumbprint>
  <CertificateStoreLocation>LocalMachine</CertificateStoreLocation>
  <CertificateStoreName>My</CertificateStoreName>
  <SitecoreMembershipOptions>
    <ConnectionString>Data Source=XXXXXX;Initial Catalog=Test_Core;User ID=securityuser;Password=ZPOgVcB1jMWadVFP0R6K</ConnectionString>
  </SitecoreMembershipOptions>
  <AccountOptions>
    <PasswordRecoveryUrl>https://test.cm.localhost/sitecore/login?rc=1</PasswordRecoveryUrl>
  </AccountOptions>
  <Clients>
    <DefaultClient>
      <AllowedCorsOrigins>
        <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://test.cm.localhost</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
      </AllowedCorsOrigins>
    </DefaultClient>
    <PasswordClient>
      <ClientSecrets>
        <ClientSecret1>IdentityServerClientSecret</ClientSecret1>
      </ClientSecrets>
    </PasswordClient>
  </Clients>
</IdentityServer>
```

I have the below entry in my CM site `connectionstrings.config` file as well:

```
<add name="sitecoreidentity.secret" connectionString="IdentityServerClientSecret" />
```

Comment: You don't have `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Disabler.config` on your CM, do you?

Comment: @MarekMusielak - I don't have that in my CM site folder

Comment: Is it by default not redirecting or it has custom config anything Like Azure AD etc.?

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Go to the certificates -> personal certificates
2. Right-click on the identity server certificate
3. Click on `All Tasks` -> `Manage Private Keys`
4. Check if the identity app pool has permission on the identity certificate or not, it must have permission.

[image]

Comment: I have added the App Pool in the certificate and provided full control. It's not solving the issue. It's going to CM login only not redirecting to IdentityServer login

Comment: Can you check the log file of the identity server?

Comment: There is no error in "identityserver" log. But in CM log, there is an error                
ERROR Unable to reach an external identity provider.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'.
Source: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols

Answer (score 1):

In my case answer is : Telerik configuration Impacted. Make sure the configuration in web.config is right or comment it to validate if used in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this may help. But, I had a similar issue once before, and below is this solution that worked for me:

Go to the webroot of your Identity Server instance, and then go to the sitecoreruntime folder.

Here, replace the license.xml file with the one you have for your CM instance.

Do an iisreset, and check if this resolves your issue.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: I have replaced the license.xml file . But no luck still. Thanks Vinay

Answer (score 0):

I think, first, you need to verify into your `CM site` webroot by going to the config

`\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config`

and check if it's set with the proper `identityserver` site value or not like below.

```
<sc.variable name="identityServerAuthority" value="https://youtsiteidentityserver.dev.local" />
```

Then you need to go to your `identityserver site` webroot and go to the config

```
\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml
```

and verify that the following is set properly with your CM site or not.

```
<AllowedCorsOrigins>
      <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://yourcmsite.dev.local</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
</AllowedCorsOrigins>
```

Hope it should work.

Comment: Hi @Sumit Bhatia, I have them in my config files as i provided in the question

Comment: Hi @user1428019 Did you check that you have the identity site entry in the host file?

Comment: Yes. It is there. I am able to hit the identity server URL https://test.identityserver.localhost/ and it's working fine in login and logout. when i login into CM, it's not taking me to Identity server site to login and on login success i want to land back to CM.

Comment: @user1428019 I think this is the only configuration where we set the identity server URL where the site redirects to login. One more place I would like you to check in the `Web.Config` and check this key look like this <add key="security:define" value="Sitecore" />

Comment: <add key="security:define" value="Sitecore" />
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="Sitecore.Owin.Startup, Sitecore.Owin" /> I have those keys

Comment: @user1428019 Go to your `connectionstring.conifg` and check that `sitecoreidentity.secret` is matching with your `ClientSecret1` key in the `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` file

Comment: Yes Sumit. That's matching as i provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. Issue was i had the different SAN/DNS in my Identity server SSL certificate and in IIS. when i have both of them in sync it works like charm.

Comment: HI @Jey Did you mean that in IIS you have selected a different SSL for your identity server?

Comment: In case my issue was i had the SSL cert issue. I had a different DNS name in my cert between the Binding Name.

Comment: Thanks but how do you update it? Is there any command?

Comment: There is a key tool command to generate the certificate. Just ensure the binding name matches the DNS name in the certificate

Comment: When you install the OOTB sites Sitecore does the same. Please let me know if you are running into the IDS redirect issue still.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found below link is very helpful:

https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/unable-to-login-to-sitecore-10-via-the-identity-server

To find out the exact issue we should run the following cmd command in the administrator mode:

Go to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxidentityserver.dev.local`

Run the below command to see the exact issue:

`dotnet .\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll`

In case of not having any issue, you see screen similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me After configuring Azure AD login, my CM url not redirected to SI server.

- Issue was below two files present in CM under `wwwroot\App_Config\Environment`>

Removed and it's started working

```
-Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Disabler
-Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Disabler
```